# Always keep a Node on top of a Pane

Tags: javafx, pane

I have a Pane where I added multiple Node. Sometimes, those node intersect.

I want to be able to handle the left click on the intersection with the handler of the Node which is added first ( so it ends up under the one added latter ).

I thought about using setMouseTransparent() on the Node added last ( the one on top ), but I can't because I need to handle right clicks with the Node on top, so I can't just make it transparent.

The solution I came up with would be to always keep the Node added first on top: this way, when clicking on the intersection, I would click on that one, so his handler who get the mouse event.

Is there a way to always keep a Node on top of other Node in a Pane with javafx ?

Comment: Have you tried `toFront()`?

Comment: Just add new nodes to the start of the list instead of the end: `pane.getChildren().add(0, newNode);`.

Comment: Simple solution but works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

#### in_short

- use eg: **`rectangle_02.setViewOrder(-1);`** for the node you want to keep on top.

  - **the lower the toper**
  - default value is **0.0** for all nodes
  - its able to pick up things like MouseEvent
- *(There arent many online resource about this. I just *tested* it out.)*

#### ex

```java
    final double opacity = 0.9;

    double width = 300;
    double height = 300;

    final Rectangle rectangle_01 = new Rectangle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(rectangle_01);
    rectangle_01.setLayoutX(200);
    rectangle_01.setLayoutY(200);
    rectangle_01.setWidth(width);
    rectangle_01.setHeight(height);
    rectangle_01.setFill(Color.rgb(128, 0, 0, opacity));

    final Rectangle rectangle_02 = new Rectangle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(rectangle_02);
    rectangle_02.setLayoutX(250);
    rectangle_02.setLayoutY(250);
    rectangle_02.setWidth(width);
    rectangle_02.setHeight(height);
    rectangle_02.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 128, 0, opacity));
    rectangle_02.setViewOrder(-1); // << @watch 
    // make_Draggable(rectangle_02, false);

    final Rectangle rectangle_03 = new Rectangle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(rectangle_03);
    rectangle_03.setLayoutX(300);
    rectangle_03.setLayoutY(300);
    rectangle_03.setWidth(width);
    rectangle_03.setHeight(height);
    rectangle_03.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 128, opacity));

    final Rectangle rectangle_04 = new Rectangle();
    panel_SemanticRoot.getChildren().add(rectangle_04);
    rectangle_04.setLayoutX(350);
    rectangle_04.setLayoutY(350);
    rectangle_04.setWidth(width);
    rectangle_04.setHeight(height);
    rectangle_04.setFill(Color.rgb(128, 128, 0, opacity));
```

#### reference

> public final [DoubleProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html) viewOrderProperty() 
>
> Defines the rendering and picking order of this `Node` within its parent. 
>
> This property is used to alter the rendering and picking order of a node within its parent without reordering the parent's `children` list. For example, this can be used as a more efficient way to implement transparency sorting. To do this, an application can assign the viewOrder value of each node to the computed distance between that node and the viewer. 
>
> The parent will traverse its `children` in decreasing `viewOrder` order. This means that a child with a lower `viewOrder` will be in front of a child with a higher `viewOrder`. If two children have the same `viewOrder`, the parent will traverse them in the order they appear in the parent's `children` list. 
>
> However, `viewOrder` does not alter the layout and focus traversal order of this Node within its parent. A parent always traverses its `children` list in order when doing layout or focus traversal. 
>
> Default value: 
> 0.0 
>
> https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty()

Comment: Maybe another way, Im not sure, if its possible to listen to the `parentNode.getChildren().add()` & auto move the `desireNode.toFront()`.